# How do I allow a user to delete a post?

Tags: node.js, http

Below I have a post request which a user can make and if the hidden form item with the name `_method` is deleted it will make a request to my own server to a different route and delete the post from the database. How should this process work?

```
 app.post("/posts/:id/delete", function(req, res){
  if(req.body._method = "delete"){
    request({
      "method": "delete",
      "url": "/posts/"+req.param.id
    }, function(err, response, body){
      res.redirect("/posts");
    });
  }
});

app.delete("/posts/:id", function(req, res){
  //delete it from the database
  res.redirect("/posts");
});
```

Comment: Why not have the user's request be an HTTP DELETE one rather than a POST which you then redirect?

Comment: @JohnZwinck http://stackoverflow.com/a/166501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Express/Connect, [`methodOverride()`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html) is probably the simplest option:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Though, the `<form action>` and route `path` should match:

```
<form action="/posts/{{id}}" method="post">
    <input type="_method" value="delete" />
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

```
app.delete('/posts/:id', function (req, res) {
  //delete it from the database
  res.redirect("/posts");
});
```

---

[Update] With Express 4 and newer, this middleware has moved to [`method-override`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override).

Comment: Had no clue that express supported this out-of-the-box.